# Can a sequence of independent RVs converge a.s. to a non-constant RV

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Can a sequence of independent random variables converge almost surely to a non-constant function?  As in, $X_n\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}X$ where $X$ is something such as $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ or $N(0,1)$?

My intuition is no, it can't.  Almost sure convergence means (with $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ any metric distance function)
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(\underset{m\geq n}{\sup} \{d(X_n,X)\}\geq \epsilon)=0$$
$$=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{m\geq n}d(X_n,X)\geq\epsilon\right)$$
$$=1-\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{m\geq n}d(X_n,X)<\epsilon\right)$$
$$=1-\mathbb{P}(d(X_n,X)<\epsilon)
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{m\geq n}d(X_m,X)<\epsilon|
d(X_n,X)<\epsilon\right)$$
This is a nice form because it includes convergence in probability as a condition, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(d(X_n,X)<\epsilon)$=1.  Going further,
$$=1-\prod_{k=n}^\infty\mathbb{P}\left(d(X_k,X)<\epsilon|
\bigcap_{n \leq m< k} d(X_m,X)<\epsilon\right)$$,
 which really shows the importance of conditional probability.

In one sense, I'm looking for a confirmation that my interpretation and math is correct.  In another sense, I'm looking for additional illuminating intuition on what sequences can and can't be ASC.  As an example, how do you interpret independence with the notation $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega)\rightarrow X(\omega)$, with $X_n(\omega)$ being a deterministic function?  Different notation often illustrates different ways of looking at probability concepts.

Comment: Ah, I see the interpretation I was looking for in the last paragraph.  $\omega$ corresponds to a single realization of the infinite sequence of random variables.  For independent $X_n$, that could be a point in the infinite product space of the unit interval, right?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_zero%E2%80%93one_law